# Wordpress Posts URLs default redirection functionality not working with WPEngine

Tags: wordpress

If any user modifies the url on browser then on my local server, it gets redirected to original post but on staging server, no such thing happens. Although full setup is same despite only wp-engine. Does wpengine has anything to do with wordpress default redirection? WPEngine exists on staging server, not on local.

For example
URL : /how-to/format
User inserts a string like /how-to/fgdfg/format

On my local server which is xampp setup, the url gets changed to /how-to/format but on staging server, it remains the same i.e. /how-to/fgdfg/format but shows the same post.

Can anybody help me on the same?

Comment: Try WP Engine support if you didn't already

Comment: I have discussed with the support team but there is nothing to do with them. My main motive is that if somebody adds any random string in between the url then 404 page should be loaded rather than redirection or showing same post.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to disable WP's built-in feature of trying to find the page it thinks you're looking for.

Use extreme caution with this as it can have adverse impact.

This answer should help you get started: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92103/disable-wordpress-url-auto-complete